# Confidence interval for variance of a given distribution

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a simple sample from a distribution given by its density:

$f_\theta(x)=\theta|x|e^{-\theta x^2}$

where $x \in \Bbb R$ and $\theta>0$. Find an exact confidence interval for variance, $1-\alpha=0.95$ and $n=12$.

Could you please give me a hint? I don't really know how to proceed when both a sample is small and a distribution is not normal. Shall I start by finding MLE?

Comment: What does '|' mean in this context?

Comment: An absolute value. @gt6989b

Comment: Have you calculated the variance? You need to use an appropriate pivot; start by finding the distribution of $X_1^2$.

Comment: And then obtain $Var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom got it, $Var(X_1) = \frac{1}{\theta}$. But I'm stuck with this pivot function.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I also got that $X^2 \sim \exp(\theta)$.

Comment: So then $2\theta\sum X_i^2 \sim \mathcal X_{2n}^2$

Comment: Yes you got it. I was searching for a similar question to link to, but perhaps you can solve it now.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks a lot! But how would I get a confidence interval then?

Comment: You can rearrange $P(a<2\theta\sum X_i^2 <b)=1-\alpha$ for some $a,b$ to get a confidence interval for $1/\theta$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Excuse me, today I'm totally exhausted. How do I get $a, b$ from $F_{\mathcal X_{2n}^2}(b)-F_{\mathcal X_{2n}^2}(a)=1-\alpha$?

Comment: $a,b$ are just chi-square quantiles. For example, $b=\chi^2_{2n,\alpha/2}$ which means $P(\chi^2_{2n}>b)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Once again:
$\Bbb P(\mathcal X_{2n}^2 \leq b) = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}\\$
and
$\Bbb P(\mathcal X_{2n}^2 \leq a) = \frac{\alpha}{2}$

and from that I get $a, b$. Then I rearrange my interval into: $\Bbb P(\frac{a}{\mathcal X_{2n}^2\theta} \leq \frac{1}{\theta} \leq \frac{b}{\mathcal X_{2n}^2\theta}) = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}$ so my $CI$ is $(\frac{a}{\mathcal X_{2n}^2\theta}, \frac{b}{\mathcal X_{2n}^2\theta})$, right?

Comment: I would ask you to edit your post to include your work as you mentioned in comments and delete unnecessary comments. This way the comment section does not get too long.

Comment: @StubbornAtom sure, I'll do that tomorrow morning. So it means that this solution is correct?